# Prevent function execution twice within two triggered events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
    myInput.change(function (e) { // this triggers first
        triggerProcess();
    });

    myButton.click(function (e) { // this triggers second
        triggerProcess();
    });
```

The problem with the above is when I click `myButton` both events are triggered and `triggerProcess()` is fired twice which is not desired.

I only need `triggerProcess()` to fire once. How can I do that?

Comment: Post the HTML as well, and what those elements really are

Comment: use e.stopimmediatepropogation

Comment: One option would be to only fire the change event - but it depends on if you need the button to fire even if the input hasn't changed.  eg if it's "input+update" then there's no need to update if hasn't changed.  In which case the button is a dummy button for the sake of UX.

Comment: @adeneo would it be safe to assume one is an input and the other is a button?  Or is that too much of a stretch?

Comment: @freedomn-m that is correct

Comment: @freedomn-m - That's probably correct, but why does an input change when you click a button ?

Comment: the input change triggers when I modify its text and then I click outside of the input

Comment: It says in the question that *"when I click myButton both events are triggered"* ? So what you really mean is you have two different events that triggers for two different user actions

Comment: myButton is outside the input, so yes....

Comment: And what if the user first blurs out of the input, does something else, like scrolls and read a bit, and then presses the button, should only the click event be fired then as well?

Comment: @adeneo in that case only the click event is firing. they both fire when I change the input text and then I click the button

Comment: Then when does the `change` event fire? How long would be a reasonable timeframe between blurring the input and clicking the button etc?

Comment: I'm not getting it, but I suspect you're just looking for this -> **https://jsfiddle.net/1q86uwf5/1/**

Comment: @adeneo the change event fires when I click outside the input after I change the input's text

Comment: And that's what it does, if you don't want that, just remove that event handler ?

Comment: @adeneo the fiddle works for me, please post it so I can accept it, thanks

Comment: So it's just when you blur the input at the moment you click the button, that you don't want the function to fire twice etc.

Comment: You can use a `debounce` on the function.   That way it waits a very short time (eg 50ms, not noticable to the user) and the second event will fire, cancelling the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mousedown` event, which will fire before the input is blurred, and then check if the input has focus by checking if it's the `activeElement`, and if it does have focus, don't fire the `mousedown` event, as the change event will fire instead.

Additionally, if you want a `mousedown` event to occur when the value hasn't changed, and the change event doesn't fire, you'll need a check for that as well

```js
var myInput = $('#test1'),
  myButton = $('#test2'),
  i = 0;

myInput.change(function(e) { // this triggers first
  $(this).data('prev', this.value);
  triggerProcess();
});

myButton.mousedown(function(e) { // this triggers second
  var inp = myInput.get(0);
  if (document.activeElement !== inp || inp.value === myInput.data('prev'))
    triggerProcess();
});

function triggerProcess() {
  console.log('triggered : ' + (++i))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test1">
<br />
<br />
<button id="test2">
  Click
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

[**Small demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/8sfuayce/1/)

You can have a static flag that disables any more triggers once the first trigger has occurred. Might look something like this:

```
var hasTriggered = false;

myInput.change(function (e) { // this triggers first
  triggerProcess();
});

myButton.click(function (e) { // this triggers second
  triggerProcess();
});

function triggerProcess () {
   // If this process has already been triggered,
   // don't execute the function
   if (hasTriggered) return;

   // Set the flag to signal that we've already triggered
   hasTriggered = true;

   // ...
}
```

For resetting the `hasTriggered` flag, that's entirely up to you and how this program works. Maybe after a certain event occurring in the program you'd want to reenable the ability to trigger this event again — all you'd need to do it set the `hasTriggered` flag back to true.

Comment: When would hasTriggered be set back to false so the events could fire properly when clicked a second time?

Comment: @Keith.Abramo Whenever he wants — depends on the program. Could be reset once a certain event occurs, or even as simple as a small `setTimeout` if he wants it to be reset after a certain amount of time. Check out my example if you want to see what I'm talking about too

Comment: This is the correct way to handle this, at least the way I've done it

Comment: To prevent code duplication - it might be a better idea to check the `hasTriggered` flag within the `triggerProcess` function.

Comment: @Lix Good idea!

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm "this is the correct way" is far too sweeping and judgemental.  It might work, and is certainly a valid answer to the question, but it's far from "**the** correct way", and this would get -ve votes from some people just for suggesting using a global variable.

Comment: @freedomn-m It depends on the program. Using static global variables can be hacky in some contexts, but in singleton patterns it would be totally fine. I do agree that this isn't a perfect solution (let alone the only correct solution), but it definitely works and solves OP's problem. With more context of their program I'm sure we'd be able to find more ways to solve this as well!

Comment: Well, I disagree with your assertion. I don't think you can come up with a cleaner and time-tested method.

Answer (score 0):

Use a real `<button>BUTTON</button>`. If you `click` on input text, alert is triggered, then once you leave the input text to click anywhere else, that *unfocuses* the input text which triggers the `change` event, so now 2 events have been triggered from the text input.

This is an assumption since the code provided is far from sufficient to give a complete and accurate answer. The HTML is needed as well as more jQuery/JavaScript. What is `myInput` and `myButton` actually referring to, etc.?

So I bet if you change...

> `var myButton = $('{whatever this is}');` and `<input type='button'>`

...**TO:**

> `var myButton = $("button");` and `<button></button>`

...you should no longer have an event trigger twice for an element.

This is assuming that `triggerProcess()` is a function that does something that doesn't manipulate the event chain or anything else involving events. This is an entirely different ballgame if instead of `click()` and `change()` methods you are using `.trigger()` or `triggerHandler()`, but it isn't. I'm not certain why such complex answers are derived from a question with very little info...?

BTW, if `myInput` is a search box and `myButton` is the button for `myInput`, as freedomn-m has mentioned, simply remove:

> `myButton.click(...`

Leave `myButton` as a dummy. The `change` event is sufficient in that circumstance.

#### SNIPPET

```js
var xInput = $('input');
var xButton = $('button'); //«———Add 

xInput.on('change', alarm);

xInput.on('click', alarm);

xButton.on('click', alarm);

function alarm() {
  return alert('Activated')
}
```

```css
/* For demo it's not required */

[type='text'] {
  width: 5ex;
}
b {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='f1' name='f1'>
  <input type='text'>

  <input type='button' value='BUTTON TYPE'>
  <label><b>⇦</b>Remove this button</label>

  <button>BUTTON TAG</button>
  <label><b>⇦</b>Replace it with this button</label>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a fairly typical scenario where you have an input with a button next to ie, eg quick search.
You want to fire when the input changes (ie onblur) but also if the user clicks the button.

In the case where the user changes the input then clicks the button without changing input focus (ie no blur), the change event fires because the text has changed and the click event fires because the button has been clicked.

One option is to *debounce* the desired event handler.

You can use a plugin or a simple setTimeout/clearTimeout, eg:

```js
$('#inp').change(debounceProcess)
$('#btn').click(debounceProcess);

function debounceProcess() {
  if (debounceProcess.timeout != null)
    clearTimeout(debounceProcess.timeout);
  debounceProcess.timeout = setTimeout(triggerProcess, 100)
}

function triggerProcess() {
  console.log('process')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inp">
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```